# makefile automatic src file detection and dependency generation

Tags: c++, makefile

I have the following setup for my c++ project:

in the src-folder, there are *.cpp and corresponding *.h files and
in the obj-folders I want to have my .o-files.

so far, compiling and linking is not the problem. But now I have too many .cpp and .h files to put them into the Makefile manually. So I decided to write this little instruction in the makefile:

```
collect_sources:
@echo "collecting source files";
@echo "SRCS = \\" > sources;
@for file in ./src/*.cpp; \
do \
    echo "$$file \\" >> sources; \
done
```

I also do

```
-include sources
```

at the beginning of the makefile

The resulting file `sources` looks fine, although there is a backslash in the last line which I don't like. But afaik it should be harmful either.

I now also need to automatically build up dependencies. In my last version in which I defined the *.cpp-files as `SRCS` directly in the Makefile, the following code was good:

```
$(SRCDIR)/%.cpp:
  @$(CXX) $(DEPFLAGS) -MT \
  "$(subst $(SRCDIR),$(OBJDIR),$(subst $(EXT_SRC),$(EXT_OBJ),$$file))" \
  $(addprefix ,$$file) >> $(DEP);
clear_dependencies:
    echo "" > $(DEP);

depend: clear_dependencies $(SRCS)
```

But with including the `sources`-file, it never reaches the upper code block.

Here are the constants defined at the top of the Makefile:

```
CXX = g++
CXXFLAGS = -Wall \
       -Wextra \
       -Wuninitialized \
       -Wmissing-declarations \
       -pedantic \
       -O3 \
       -p -g -pg
LDFLAGS =  -p -g -pg
DEPFLAGS = -MM

SRCDIR  = ./src
OBJDIR  = ./obj

TARGET = ./bin/my_funky_function_which_is_not_the_real_name

-include sources

OBJSTMP =   $(SRCS:.cpp=.o)
OBJS        =   $(OBJSTMP:$(SRCDIR)=$(OBJDIR))
DEP = depend.main
EXT_SRC =   .cpp
EXT_OBJ =   .o
```

What am I missing? Is my approach valid/feasible?

Comment: on a side note: please do not suggest any tool that does that allready. I really want to understand this and have full control over whats happening.

Comment: There is one simple error and a lot of possible improvement. How far do you want to go?

Comment: step by step to the absolute optimum ;-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All right, you asked for it.

**1:** Your `collect_sources:... include sources` is glorious Rube Goldberg hackery. Just do this:

```
SRCS = $(wildcard ./src/*.cpp)
```

And if you want to confirm it by eye, you can do this:

```
$(info $(SRCS))
```

**2:**

```
clear_dependencies:
    echo "" > $(DEP);
```

Just for the sake of aesthetics, let's fix this.

```
clear_dependencies:
    $(RM) $(DEP);
```

**3:**

```
$(SRCDIR)/%.cpp:
    @$(CXX) $(DEPFLAGS) -MT \
  "$(subst $(SRCDIR),$(OBJDIR),$(subst $(EXT_SRC),$(EXT_OBJ),$$file))" \
  $(addprefix ,$$file) >> $(DEP);
```

This will take some work. First the immediate problem: the target is a real file which exists, and the rule has no prerequisites. Therefore the rule will not be run (I have no idea why it worked for you in a previous version, maybe something else was different). As a temporary fix I suggest we switch to a static pattern rule and PHONY targets:

```
.PHONY:$(SRCS)
$(SRCS) : $(SRCDIR)/%.cpp:
    @$(CXX) $(DEPFLAGS) -MT \
   ...
```

See if all that works, then we can tackle the big stuff.

Comment: First of all, thanks for your answer. I do not understand what you mean by "the target is a real file which exists". you're right that it wasn't that code originally. instead of $$file it was something with an @.

Comment: @stefan, probably `$@`. In practice, Make will use this rule when considering whether to rebuild something like `./src/foo.cpp`. This will almost certainly be a file that already exists (unless there's more to this problem than you've told us). So Make will conclude that the file is up to date and need not be rebuilt. Even if/when Make runs the rule, I don't think the `$$file` stuff will work.

Comment: you're absolutely right. and with your "PHONY" suggestion and "$@" it works fine :)

Comment: Cool. In a few hours I'll have time to add more.

Comment: In fact that would be brilliant :) For some reason I don't understand yet, the compiler builds every object without any file change. I probably have messed up here..

Comment: No, it's a side-effect of making the sources PHONY targets.