# Makefile improvements, dependency generation not functioning

Tags: c++, makefile, gnu-make

I'm currently trying to build a proper Makefile.

What I want is full control of what's happening, so I don't want any third party software.

My current attempt seems logic to me, but since the dependency generation is not valid, I'm kind of stuck.

For better readabilty, the full Makefile is broken into little pieces. I would appreciate any comment on any section if there's something to improve.

First of all, I have the following static definitions

```
CXX = g++
CXXFLAGS = -Wall \
           -Wextra \
           -Wuninitialized \
           -Wmissing-declarations \
           -pedantic \
           -O3 \
           -p -g -pg
LDFLAGS =  -p -g -pg
DEPFLAGS = -MM
```

Afaik this should be fine. It would be perfect to make the profiling flags optional but that's not important.

```
SRC_DIR = ./src
OBJ_DIR = ./obj
SRC_EXT = .cpp
OBJ_EXT = .o

TARGET = ./bin/my_target

SRCS = $(wildcard $(SRC_DIR)/*$(SRC_EXT))
OBJS = $(subst $(SRC_DIR), $(OBJ_DIR), $(SRCS:$(SRC_EXT)=$(OBJ_EXT)))
DEP = depend.main
```

Basically, this should just extract all the `*.cpp` files out of the subfolder `src` and additionally replace `./src` with `./obj` and `.cpp` with `.o` as names of the objects.

```
.PHONY: clean all depend

all: $(TARGET)

$(TARGET): $(OBJS)
    @echo "-> linking $@"
    @$(CXX) $^ $(LDFLAGS) -o $@

$(OBJ_DIR)/%.$(EXT_OBJ):
    @echo "-> compiling $@"
    @$(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
```

Afaik, this block - provided a valid dependency file exists - should do all necessary compiling and linking.

```
clean:
    @echo "removing objects and main file"
    @rm -f $(OBJS) $(TARGET)
```

Should be self-explanatory and correct, or am I missing something here?

```
$(SRC_DIR)/%.$(SRC_EXT): 
    $(CXX) $(DEPFLAGS) -MT \
    "$(subst $(SRC_DIR),$(OBJ_DIR),$(subst $(SRC_EXT),$(OBJ_EXT),$@))" \
    $(addprefix ,$@) >> $(DEP);

clear_dependencies:
    @echo "-> (re-)building dependencies";
    @$(RM) $(DEP)

depend: clear_dependencies $(SRCS)
```

This is the non-functional part. What I intend to do is using the `g++` Compiler flag `-MM` to auto-create dependencies and using `-MT` to use a different path than the default one.
The resulting dependency should look like

```
./obj/main.o: ./src/main.cpp ./src/some_header_file.h
```

Unfortunately, this will never be called and I lack the knowledge why this is the case.
In a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10452507/makefile-automatic-src-file-detection-and-dependency-generation), user Beta gladly provided a temporary solution by adding a `.Phony` but this has the side effect on rebuilding every object without any change.

Finally, there is just the one line

```
-include $(DEP)
```

to include the dependency file, once created.

Any answer providing some hints about any part are very welcome.
So my question is: What can I do better or maybe "cleaner" and why doesn't the dependency generation work?

Comment: Hmph! I told you the `PHONY` trick was just a stopgap, and we'd cover dependency handling in the next iteration. If you want to call for other opinions, fine, but don't go telling people I gave you slipshod advice.

Comment: sorry this is an misunderstanding. I'm happy to have your answer but wanted to create a more detailed question. This would have been messy if just updated the old one. I very much appreciate your effort and answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here goes.

---

Assign [*simply expanded* variables](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Setting) where possible:

```sh
SRCS := $(wildcard $(SRC_DIR)/*$(SRC_EXT))
```

From [GNU Make manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Flavors):

> Another disadvantage [of recursively expanded variables] is that any functions referenced in the definition will be executed every time the variable is expanded. This makes `make` run slower; worse, it causes the `wildcard` and `shell` functions to give unpredictable results because you cannot easily control when they are called, or even how many times.

---

Use [substitution references](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Substitution-Refs) or [`patsubst` function](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Text-Functions) to convert sources into objects:

```sh
OBJS := $(SRCS:$(SRC_DIR)/%$(SRC_EXT)=$(OBJ_DIR)/%$(OBJ_EXT))
```

---

Specify proper prerequisites in compilation pattern rule. This is **mandatory** to get Make keeping your object files up to date and updating them on source changes.

```sh
$(OBJ_DIR)/%$(OBJ_EXT) : $(SRC_DIR)/%$(SRC_EXT)
    @echo "-> compiling $@"
    @$(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $@ -c $<
```

---

Compile sources and generate dependency files for them at the same time. Use `-MMD -MP` flags to get things work (just append them to `CXXFLAGS`).

```sh
CXXFLAGS += -MMD -MP

-include $(OBJS:$(OBJ_EXT)=.d)
```

From [GCC manual](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html):

> `-MD`
>
> `-MD` is equivalent to `-M -MF` *file*, except that `-E` is not implied. The driver determines file based on whether an -o option is given. If it is, the driver uses its argument but with a suffix of `.d`, otherwise it takes the name of the input file, removes any directory components and suffix, and applies a `.d` suffix.
>
> `-MMD`
>
> Like `-MD` except mention only user header files, not system header files.
>
> `-MP`
>
> This option instructs CPP to add a phony target for each dependency other than the main file, causing each to depend on nothing. These dummy rules work around errors `make` gives if you remove header files without updating the `Makefile` to match.

Also consider studying [this article](http://mad-scientist.net/make/autodep.html) of Paul Smith (he is a maintainer of GNU Make). It gives a rather good overview of different autodep-generation approaches.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, it works quite well. I do not understand if my variables are "simple" enough, is there any potential improvement left or is this the optimum?

Comment: @stefan, using simply expanded variable instead of a recursive one can be faster when its value calls a non-trivial function like `wildcard`. Personally I use recursively expanded variables only for defining custom "functions", which are invoked using [`call` function](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Call-Function).

Comment: @stefan, this is an excellent answer, and the Paul Smith article is what I was working up to. I'll see if I have anything to add, and edit my answer in the other question.

Comment: @Beta: thank you very much! I appreciate your effort very much and also like this answer. if I could, I would upvote this and your answer multiple times, because it's not just the solution. It's a perfect explanation I could learn so much with. So once again, thank you both for your good work!

Comment: @stefan, you're welcome! In fact, I've upvoted and bookmarked both your questions for the same reasons. ;-)