# GNU Make. Why this complex syntax to generate dependencies?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I'm reading Managing Projects with GNU Make, and found this example in Chapter 2.7 - Automatic Dependency Generation. The Author says their from the GNU manual:

```
%.d: %c
        $(CC) -M $(CPPFLAGS $< > $@.$$$$; \
              sed s',\($*\)\.o[ :]*,\1.o $@ : ,g' < $@.$$$$ > $@; \
              rm -f $@.$$$$
```

However, I was able to do the same thing with this (note the `sed`):

```
-include $(subst .c,.d,$(SOURCES))

%.d: %.c
          @$(CC) -M $(CPPFLAGS) $<  | sed 's|:| $*.d : |'  > $@;
```

All these lines do is generate the dependencies, then add in the `*.d` name. They had to change the first line from:

```
  foo.o: bar.h foo.h fubar.h
```

to
      foo.o foo.d : bar.h foo.h fubar.h

Mine is simpler and seems to work quite well, but I assume that the GNU folks had a reason for their `sed` command. Also:

- Why do a redirect of the file into `sed`? Why not simply take it as a commond line parameter
- Why not skip the intermediary file completely?

I know the guys at GNU could have thought of these too, but for some reason, went with the more complex setup. I just want to understand their reasoning, so I can do these on the fly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Addressing the question: `Why do a redirect of the file into sed?`  If you do:

```
@$(CC) -M $(CPPFLAGS) $<  | sed 's|:| $*.d : |'  > $@;
```

and the compilation fails (errors out and generates no output), you will create an empty target file.  When `make` is run again, it will see the newly created empty file and not regenerate it, leading to build errors.  Using intermediate files is a common defensive strategy to avoid accidentally created an empty target.

Comment: That's the explanation that I was looking for. Mine will create the empty file even if the compile fails. The GNU guys version won't.

Answer (score 13):

Actually even the rule itself is not necessary. There is a great overview of different approaches of generating Make-style dependencies in [Advanced Auto-Dependency Generation](http://make.mad-scientist.net/autodep.html) article written by Paul D. Smith.

After all, the following rule should be enough (in case of using GCC):

```
%.o: %.c
    $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) -MMD -MP -o $@ -c $<

-include $(SOURCES:.c=.d)
```

### UPD.

I have also [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10456349/545027) a similar question a bit earlier. It contains an explanation (quotation of GCC manual) of `-MMD -MP` options.

Comment: I like your `include` directive much better than the one in the book. It's simpler and easier to understand. Unfortunately, for some reason your `%.o %.c` rule missed building the dependency for one of the files. I'm going to have to delve deeper into the vast diversity of `gcc` command parameters.

Comment: @David Hmm... That looks strange. `-MMD -MP` options always make their magic for me.

Comment: @DavidW., could you give us a minimal example which causes the rule to fail?

Comment: @Beta Nothing "fails", it just doesn't create dependencies one of the files. This is from the ORLY GNU book. I think Chap 2.7. Makefile is in [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/pXBhuQsG). It might have to do with the way I've defined the link dependencies. I don't have `count_words` depend upon `count_words.o` since that's default. I haven't tried to chase down the issue.

Comment: @Beta I add in the `count_words.o` dependency for `count_words` and it now works.

Comment: `-MP` is optional but very useful. Without it if a header file has been removed or renamed the generated dependency will cause it's target to fail.

Comment: This is great. Yet, why doesn't Paul Smith use your simple way in his article? He also used `-MT`, `-MF` options and a `POSTCOMPILE` command.

Comment: @nn0p there's an explanation in the last section of that article. `First rename the generated temporary dependency file to the real dependency file. We do this in a separate step so that failures during the compilation won’t leave a corrupted dependency file. Second touch the object file; it’s been reported that some versions of GCC may leave the object file older than the dependency file, which causes unnecessary rebuilds.`

Answer (score 4):

An even simpler solution is to get rid of the sed call completely, as gcc can do everything you need directly:

```
%.d: %.c
        $(CC) -M $(CPPFLAGS) -MF $@ $< -MT "$*.o $@"
```

Comment: Hey, that works for me! I have never delved deep into the mysteries of `gcc` and it's multitude of command line options. However, this works great.