# What's the common way to resolve dependencies in Makefile?

Tags: c++, c, makefile

I've seen lots of methods been used to resolved the dependencies in Makefile, such as using `gcc -MM` and `sed` commond, or using the `include` directive (plus a little Perl magic), or `qmake`, or `automake`, or `info make`, etc.

Facing such many options, I am confused of which should I choose. So, I wanna know what's the common way to resolve dependencies in Makefile nowadays? What's the best way to cope with this  problem?

PS: C/CPP project.

Comment: it depends on the situations, can you maybe explain a little bit about your makefile issues so we can better help you?

Comment: It also potentially depends on what platforms you need to support (how portable you need to be).

Comment: @pyCthon actually, the problem is simple dependency issues. Such as on header file is modified, re-running the `make` command will only re-generate the corresponding object file. What I wanna know is the `best` or `common` way to resolve this issue. Thanks.

Comment: @Jirka Hanika what if only wanna deploy my project on Linux?

Comment: @injoy to always include a clean option is one simple tip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally if all you care about is systems that support GNU make and gcc (such as all linux variants and most unix like systems these days), you just use gcc's various `-M` flags to generate the dependencies and then `-include` them in your Makefile.  There's some good info [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10694403/gnu-make-why-this-complex-syntax-to-generate-dependencies) -- generally there's no need to use sed or any more complex tools.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to support lots of Linux distributions (as you noted in a comment), then I'd recommend the `automake/autoconf` suite.

This answer assumes you are only asking generally and you do not yet know what specific issues you will have to resolve as you go.

**Edit**:

GNU make alone can handle dependency generation within your own project.

`autoconf` handles optional or alternative dependencies on third party libraries, tools or system features.  `automake` provides [macros](http://sunsite.ualberta.ca/Documentation/Gnu/automake-1.5/html_node/automake_88.html) some of which are occasionally useful even if you are otherwise using `autoconf` without `automake`.

A side benefit of starting with `automake` outright is that your makefiles will behave completely predictably (in terms of conventions and portability) with less investment of attention.

Hence my humble recommendation.

Comment: automake/autoconf is really only needed if you need to support NON-linux systems.  If all you care about is Linux, just use GNUmake

Comment: @ChrisDodd - +1 to your answer.  I expanded my answer now that you have helped me to better understand the focus of this question.  I suspect that mine may be based on somewhat outdated personal experience but I will let the community to judge that.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to generate make-compatible dependencies for C/C++ projects:

- `gcc -M`, which comes in several flavors and is sort of "the gold standard" in terms of accuracy, since it uses the actual compiler to generate the dependencies, and who would know better how to process `#include` statements than the compiler itself?
- [`makedepend`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Makedepend), which is generally discouraged in favor of compiler-generated dependencies.
- [`fastdep`](http://freecode.com/projects/fastdep), another third-party dependency generator which purports to be faster than `gcc -M`.
- [ElectricAccelerator](http://www.electric-cloud.com/products/electricaccelerator-dev.php) has a built-in feature called *autodep* which uses the filesystem usage activity of the commands invoked in the build to generate dependency information.  The advantage of autodep over the alternatives is that it is extremely fast and completely tool and programming language independent -- while the others are all tied to C/C++ or require the use of a specific compiler, autodep works with all types of build tools.

I did a [performance comparison](http://www.electric-cloud.com/blog/2008/12/15/automatic-dependency-management-with-electricaccelerator/) of several of these options a while back.

Disclaimer: I am the architect and lead developer of ElectricAccelerator.