# GNU Make: Using % in a pattern-rule macro

Tags: variables, macros, makefile

I'm trying to build a pattern-rule that allows me to use `%` in a macro call and I'm not getting the results I expect.

The pattern-rule:

```
%.o: %.cpp $(%_H)
    g++ -o $@ $(FLAGS) -c $<
```

The problem is with the $(%_H)

For some reason `%` isn't expanding to what it is defined to.

When I print out the dependency list `($^)`, only the source file prints.

I have a very clean way of setting up my dependencies that I would like to use:

```
# Header Dependencies per object 
Geometry_H:=Geometry.h $(Error_H) 
Enemy_H:=Enemy.h $(Geometry_H) $(Error_H) 
Surface_H:=Surface.h $(Geometry_H) 
Player_H:=Player.h $(Geometry_H) $(Surface_H) 
SDLWindow_H:=SDLWindow.h $(Surface_H) $(Error_H) 
Path_H:=Path.h $(Geometry_H) $(Error_H) 
Territory_H:=Territory.h $(Geometry_H) 
Board_H:=Board.h $(Territory_H) $(Geometry_H) $(Player_H) $(Path_H) $(Enemy_H) $(Error_H) 
Error_H:=Error.h 
Diminisher_H:=Diminisher.h $(SDLWindow_H) $(Geometry_H) $(Surface_H) $(Board_H) $(Error_H) 
Main_H:=$(Diminisher_H)
```

Another person has suggested that I change these variables into dependency lists.

I.e.
Main_H:=$(Diminisher_H)

becomes
Main.o: $(Diminisher_H)

This is a good fix, it works.
However, the problem still remains that `$(%_H)` is somehow invalid.

I would like to know how (if possible) to make it a valid expression.

I've tried `$( $%_H )`, `$( $(%)_H )`, `$( $(value %)_H )` and many more.
It seems like `%` just loses its meaning when in a macro call.

Is there no way to use `%` in a macro call?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either use [secondary expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Secondary-Expansion):

```
.SECONDEXPANSION:

%.o: %.cpp $$($$*_H)
    g++ -o $@ $(FLAGS) -c $<
```

Or (IMO, better) use dependency auto-generation:

- [An answer to another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10700187/545027)
- [Advanced Auto-Dependency Generation](http://mad-scientist.net/make/autodep.html) article

Comment: Thank you. A secondary expansion did the trick. However, when I tried using $$($$%_H), the problem persisted. Only when I used $$($$*_H) would the expression expand correctly. It looks like GNU make just might not like % being used in a macro call? Also, I appreciate the additional information. I'll be needing to upgrade to automatic dependency generation sometime... maybe not for this project.

Comment: @SexyBachelor Percent sign has a special meaning inside pattern rules, just don't use it. `$*` is [automatic variable](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Automatic-Variables) and it expands into the stem which the rule matches, that is, the percent sign.