# GNU Make: How to perform second expansion with suffix-changing substitution

Tags: makefile, substitution, variable-expansion

## What I'm going for (what's failing)

I have a list of dependencies for each file:

```
point_deps =
bounds_deps = point
triangle_deps = point bounds
Image_deps = types bounds triangle
main_deps = Image triangle bounds point types
```

I'd like to write a rule to include the relevant dependencies. Here's my best attempt:

```
out/%.o: src/%.cpp src/%.h $$($$*_deps:%=src/%.h)
  g++ -o $@ -c $<
```

I expect `$*` to evaluate to, for instance, "main". Then the [suffix-changing substitution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12071918/1433127) should change each entry in the dependency list to begin with "src/" and end with ".h".

When I try to run the code above, I get an error (on the `out/%.o` line):

```
makefile:26: *** multiple target patterns.  Stop.
```

## What's working (non-optimal)

For now I have to create a separate variable for each file's header dependencies:

```
point_deps_h = $(point_deps:%=src/%.h)
bounds_deps_h = $(bounds_deps:%=src/%.h)
triangle_deps_h = $(triangle_deps:%=src/%.h)
Image_deps_h = $(Image_deps:%=src/%.h)
main_deps_h = $(main_deps:%=src/%.h)
```

Then I can use [secondary-expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10870114/1433127) to include the correct header files:

```
out/%.o: src/%.cpp src/%.h $$($$*_deps_h)
    g++ -o $@ -c $<
```

Comment: Use `$$(addprefix src/,$$(addsuffix .h,$$*_deps))` instead? But that's not going to recursively expand the `*_deps` variables in the lists if you are expecting that to work.

Comment: Hi Etan, thanks for the suggestion. I've tried all kinds of variations without luck. That one also doesn't work, giving the error: `make: *** No rule to make target 'out/main.o', needed by 'raster'.  Stop.`

Comment: @EtanReisner: I think you meant `...$$($$*_deps)))` (and I don't think recursive expansion is called for).

Comment: @Beta I believe you are correct. I wrote it in the comment box. And the "recursion" I meant was that if you look at the values of the deps listed they nest. `point` is listed as an entry in `bounds`, etc. I wasn't sure if those were just supposed to be filenames or if they were supposed to be recursively nested lists so I figured I'd mention it.

Comment: That works! `$$(addprefix src/,$$(addsuffix .h,$$($$*_deps)))` works, `$$($$($$*_deps):%=src/%.h)` does not (what I had tried all the variations with). Ahh. Anyway, thank you both for your help! Would either of you like to write the answer to accept?

Comment: Also, to clarify questions about the dependency lists: bounds.cpp and bounds.h are source files, bounds.h depends on (directly includes and uses functions/classes from) point.h

Comment: Short-form pattern substitution doesn't work well with prerequisites because the `:` confuses make, since it's not inside a variable during the first pass.  Your solution with `addprefix` and `addsuffix` is fine, but more directly applicable is `patsubst`: `$$(patsubst %,src/%.h,$$($$*_deps))`.  The short-form pattern substitution is just syntactic sugar for `patsubst` and they are always directly interchangeable using the obvious translations.  Cheers!