# Top-Directory Makefile with Multiple Sources

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a project in which I'm required to use a Makefile to have directory hierarchy be in the form of

```
[user@machine program]$ ls
bin  build  CHANGELOG  Makefile  src
```

My attempts to create such a Makefile have been, thus far, fruitless.  Here's my thoughts:

1) Define some hopefully useful things

```
SRCDIR    =$(PWD)/src    # Keep multiple *.cpp and *.h files in here
BUILDDIR  =$(PWD)/build  # Build all appropriate *.o files
BINDIR    =$(PWD)/bin    # Compile/link all *.o files for final executable

PROJ      = program      #This is the name of the final executable
```

And then define the other things like a compiler, some library links, etc (I'm not worried about those).

2) The all target:

```
all: $(BINDIR)/$(PROJ)
```

3) The dependency of the all target:

```
$(BINDIR)/$(PROJ): $(BUILDDIR)/%.o
    $(CPP) $^ -o $@
```

4) Finally, the *.cpp files

```
$(BUILDDIR)/%.o: $(SRCDIR)/%.cpp $(SRCDIR)/%.h
    $(CPP) -c $(CFLAGS) $<
```

5) What actually happens?

```
[user@machine program]$ make
make: *** No rule to make target `/home/user/program/build/%.o', needed by `/home/user/program/bin/program'.  Stop.
```

So I feel like my current mistake is in my rule for my final executable, but I'm uncertain on how to mend it.

Any thoughts on this? Any input is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you're right. In the third step (`$(BINDIR)/$(PROJ): $(BUILDDIR)/%.o`) you mix explicit and implicit rules.

You have to somehow provide a list of objects to link them together. The most common ways are either to transform names of all existing source files (see [`wildcard`](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Wildcard-Function) function) into the corresponding object files or to list them explicitly.

```
SRCS := $(wildcard $(SRCDIR)/*.cpp)
OBJS := $(SRCS:$(SRCDIR)/%.cpp=$(BUILDDIR)/%.o)
```

Now your linking rule should look like:

```
$(BINDIR)/$(PROJ): $(OBJS)
    $(CPP) $^ -o $@
```

### Few more notes:

1. Usually `CPP` variable name stands for C PreProcessor, and C++ compiler is `CXX`. From [GNU Make manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Implicit-Variables):

   > `CC` Program for compiling C programs; default `‘cc’`.
   >
   > `CXX` Program for compiling C++ programs; default `‘g++’`.
   >
   > `CPP` Program for running the C preprocessor, with results to standard output; default `‘$(CC) -E’`.
2. Adding just `$(SRCDIR)/%.h` prerequisite does not guarantee the integrity of incremental builds. Just suppose that `foo.cpp` includes `foo.h` and `bar.cpp` includes `bar.h` and `foo.h`. Then modifying `foo.h` will only trigger compilation of `foo.cpp`, however you might expect that `bar.cpp` would be recompiled as well. Instead of trying to track header dependencies by hand, use one of the approaches described in [Advanced Auto-Dependency Generation](http://make.mad-scientist.net/autodep.html) article. I've also described one of them in my [earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10700187/545027) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10456349/545027).

Comment: Excellent! Thanks for the help; this worked exactly as I needed!