# GNU make: clean target depends on includes

Tags: makefile, dependencies, gnu-make

I'm using gmake and `gcc -MM` to track header dependencies, following [the manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Prerequisites.html). The mechanism relies on a makefile `include` directive to import the computed dependencies.

Because the `.d` files are included by the makefile, they must exist for any target to be made, including `clean`. So before `clean` can do the right thing, the dependencies must be generated, and if one fails to build then `clean` just made more mess.

Besides `clean`, it wants to make all the dependencies before building any target.

Furthermore, if any file is changed to include a nonexistent file, then the dependency resolution breaks and nothing at all will build.

If a header is deleted, then the existing dependency files contain still name it as a target, and nothing will build until the offending dependency files are removed… which can't be done with `clean`.

Replacing the substitution pattern of the `include` with a wildcard to include all preexisting dependency files solves some of the issues, but it still can't clean out a broken dependency, and stale dependency files are never removed. Is there a better solution? Is the manual's example really intended for real use?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Just don't provide a rule for generating `.d` files. A good explanation of why it is not so good (including your case too) is available in ["Advanced Auto-Dependency Generation"](http://mad-scientist.net/make/autodep.html) of Paul Smith - a maintainer of GNU Make.

In a nutshell, the following pattern works fine for me for all cases:

```
CPPFLAGS += -MMD -MP

%.o: %.c
    $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ -c $<

-include $(OBJS:.o=.d)
```

See also my previous related answers:

- [GNU Make. Why this complex syntax to generate dependencies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10694403/gnu-make-why-this-complex-syntax-to-generate-dependencies/10700187#10700187)
- [Makefile improvements, dependency generation not functioning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10455480/makefile-improvements-dependency-generation-not-functioning/10456349#10456349)

Comment: @Potatoswatter, no. In this case generation of .d files is combined with the actual compilation, GCC performs these steps within a single invocation.

Comment: Sorry, I shouldn't have spoken before reading a little more. It looks like `-MP` solves the remaining issue after what sehe solved. But I prefer to keep objects in another directory from sources, and might want more processing of the dependency files to support precompiled headers.

Comment: @Potatoswatter, I have never used PCH before, however splitting directories for objects and sources isn't a big problem. Just prefix target and prerequisite with paths: `$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: $(SRC_DIR)/%.c`. Dependency files will be placed just near the object files, in `$(OBJ_DIR)`.

Comment: One tweak of this admirable method: If someone deletes `f.d` say, and then edits `f.h`, then `make` will not recompile `f.o` (as no one has told it `f.o: f.h`). In this case you can get `make` to delete any `.o` files that do not have a corresponding `.d` file. Add this to the end of the makefile: `${OBJS:.o=.d}: ; rm ${@:.d=.o}`

Comment: @bobbogo  How does your rule work?  It makes a .d file depend on nothing; how should that tell make that the .o file depends on it?

Comment: @Daniel Sketch: Remember, you have told make to include `f.d` (say). This tells make that `Makefile` depends on `f.d`. If `f.d` is missing, make will try to build it. If it succeeds in this building, make concludes that the make syntax it has just read in is out of date, so make will start again from the very beginning. Well, we gave make a recipe to build `f.d`. Make successfully runs this recipe, and in the process deletes `f.o`. It therefore re-starts. During this second run it discovers `f.o` is missing and all is well. Sheesh.

Comment: @bobbogo Wow! (had to add this to make the comment long enough)

Comment: @bobbogo your method seems to prevent parallel make from working correctly

Comment: @Daniel How so? Seems perfectly compatible with parallel _make_ IMHO. [P.S. the original reason for adding the rule that I gave is wrong. _make_ will work properly in the case given—that's what the `-MP` is all about. However, there is still a problem with missing `.d` files. Imagine editing a required `.h`, and deleting the `.d` in question. Now, when you run _make_, it needs to recompile the `.c` (because the `.h` has changed), but won't know this because it has no `.d`. Gnah!]

Comment: @bobbogo until I deleted those rules, each thread of the parallel make was deleting things and then rebuilding them; non-monotonic computations, such as deletes and then makes, are a disaster in the parallel world as the threads are fighting with each other; removing the rule you suggested fixed it; second I gen the .d files into another directory that I don't edit so there is no reason for a .d file to ever be missing unless the file to be generated is also missing

Comment: @Daniel No sorry, still don't see the problem. In my formulation, _make_ deletes any `.o` that does not have a corresponding `.d`. It does this in parallel (as in: all the `.o`s that need deleting get deleted in parallel with each other). It does this before trying to build any `.o` (as in: all the deletions are finished before any compiling starts). Can't see where the disconnect is in your system sadly.

Comment: @bobbogo Well *empirically*, using your rule different threads of my makefile fight with one another, one deleting files and another building them again, leading to a mess.  As soon as I turn off your rule, that stops.  So perhaps try it yourself with make -j ?

Comment: @Daniel Yes of course I use this all the time without issues. Just tried it now with 32 source files. Seemingly you have a bug somewhere and your Makefile maybe isn't doing what you think it should. That sounds like something worth teasing out.

Comment: @Daniel Maybe you are confused by the `rm: cannot remove ‘18.o’: No such file or directory` messages? These are benign. You can silence the `rm` by using `rm -f`. You can if you wish delete only those `.o` files which do not have existing `.d` files. In _make_ this means making a list of these things. So instead of a rule for all `.d` files, just have a rule for `.d` files without a `.o`. Rather than using `${OBJS:.o=.d}:` for the list of `.d`s, try something like `$(filter-out ${OBJS:.o=.d},$(wildcard *.d)):`

Comment: @bobbogo So you are saying what you told me to do above does not work correctly?  Anyway, getting rid of this trick you recommended to me cost me a few hours of my time; I really don't appreciate that.

Comment: @Daniel Sorry Dan, really didn't mean to waste any of your time. None at all. Sorry.

Comment: @bobbogo I was a bit annoyed when I wrote that, but it is a fact.  Worrying about deleted .d files is a minor point, especially if you gen .o and .d files into their own directory just for that purpose.  Further, I may not understand exactly how it is messing up my parallel build, but it really seems to be the case that it is; if you are not getting that result, I don't understand what is going on.

Comment: @Daniel Parallel programming is one area where you need a strong grip of what is going on. There is no substitute for this.

Comment: Can I understand the whole mechanism as follows: GPU make checks two dependency relations, one for makefiles themselves, and one for the "real" targets. Once make completes execution all the rules, it won't quit immediately. It checks the dependency relation for makefiles, and if make finds outdated makefiles, it will restart reading makefiles from scratch, deleting previous targets as intermediate objects before that reading.

Answer (score 10):

The solution is to use [Conditional Syntax](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Conditional-Syntax.html):

```
ifneq ($(MAKECMDGOALS), clean)
-include $(notdir $(SOURCES:.cpp=.d))
endif
```

This makes the clean target do not invoke the `*.d` targets, since when you run `make clean` the `*.d` files will not be included in the Makefile.

Reference: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Goals.html

Answer (score 2):

My usual pattern looks like

```
all: target
target: .depends

## [snip build rules]

.depends:
     gcc -MM $(CPPFLAGS) .... > $@

-include .depends
```

Note `-include` instead of `include`. Basically, it includes conditionally: i.e. iff file exists

See documentation: http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Include

Comment: +1: adding the minus sign fixed the immediate problem. Thanks, now I'm pointed in the right direction…

Comment: It is sub-optimal and unnecessary to have a rule to generate dependencies these days. Dependencies are better generated as a by-product of compilation. For the first compilation dependencies are unnecessary since every source needs to be built. Only for subsequent builds dependencies are needed and they have been produced by a previous build.

Comment: @MaximYegorushkin I learn everyday. Nice. (I do read the other answers too :))