# C++ makefile and correct (sufficient?) flag for optimization

Tags: c++, makefile

Using the the makefile [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10455480/makefile-improvements-dependency-generation-not-functioning), I want to compile my project with -O2. The only `FLAGS` I am using is

```
CXX = g++
CXXFLAGS = 
LDFLAGS  = -O2
DEPFLAGS = -MM
```

Is it wise and safe just to use `-O2` as `LDFLAGS`? The only thing I want to do with the executable file is to execute it on my machine, nothing else.. i.e., the program is ready to be shipped.

Comment: I think you want to compile with `-O2` flag, not link with it.

Comment: Do you have recommendations for which linker-flags to use?

Comment: As far as optimizations go - not really. Compiler optimizes, linker links. Linker does not have any code-optimizations. Maybe, some loading flags for the loader, but you'd have to look in it yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should have `CXXFLAGS=-O2` (and I'd proably add probably `-Wall -Werror` as well)