# can automake detect src files and dependencies for fortran

Tags: makefile, fortran, automake

I am trying to build my fortran project using gnu-autotools.
Initially, I was giving all dependency by hand in Makefile.am as:

```
bin_PROGRAMS = kkr
kkr_SOURCES =   src/constants.f90       src/init.f90        src/util.f90\
                src/main.f90            src/symgen.f90      src/mainmodule.f90 \
                src/gengrp.f90          src/linops.f90      src/gencrystal.f90\
                src/seitz.f90           src/spgdat.f90      
src/constants.o : src/constants.f90 
src/gencrystal.o : src/gencrystal.f90 src/gengrp.o src/spgdat.o src/symgen.o src/mainmodule.o src/constants.o 
src/gengrp.o : src/gengrp.f90 src/util.o src/seitz.o src/constants.o 
src/init.o : src/init.f90 src/util.o src/constants.o src/mainmodule.o 
src/linops.o : src/linops.f90 src/mainmodule.o src/constants.o 
src/main.o : src/main.f90 src/gencrystal.o src/init.o src/mainmodule.o src/constants.o 
src/mainmodule.o : src/mainmodule.f90 src/constants.o 
src/seitz.o : src/seitz.f90 src/mainmodule.o src/constants.o 
src/spgdat.o : src/spgdat.f90 src/util.o src/constants.o src/mainmodule.o 
src/symgen.o : src/symgen.f90 src/util.o src/constants.o src/mainmodule.o 
src/util.o : src/util.f90 src/constants.o 
kkr_LDADD = 
EXTRA_DIST= autogen.sh
CLEANFILES =*.mod
```

but quickly its more pain then help. So, I am trying to write Makefile.am that will check the source code and the dependencies for the build.

I googled, and it seems there is a wildcard for the dependencies, as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10452507/makefile-automatic-src-file-detection-and-dependency-generation) for c++ and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18463947/how-to-compile-multi-folder-fortran-project-having-interfaces-modules-and-subro)..but those are for Makefile, not Makefile.am.

I was trying something like

```
bin_PROGRAMS = kkr
kkr_SOURCES = $(wildcard ./src/*.f90)
```

but, now, it does not have the build:

```
$ make
make  all-am
make[1]: Entering directory '${HOME}/Programs/dream'
gcc  -g -O2   -o kkr   -llapack 
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.9.2/../../../../lib64/crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
```

Kindly help.